# Calculate vx, vy and vz components from Lat,Lon, height and Time

Tags: spherical-geometry

Referring to the following post [Calculate velocity x and y components from Lat,Lon and Time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253821/calculate-velocity-x-and-y-components-from-lat-lon-and-time/283015?noredirect=1#comment452697_283015)

Given the two points with Latitude, Longitude, Height and time

```
P0 = (Lat0,Lon0, h0, time0)
```

and

```
P1 = (Lat1,Lon1, h1, time1)
```

how can we calculate the velocities in X, Y and Z-directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go would be to find the Earth-centered XYZ coordinates of your 2 points with [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates), then rotate them to find the ENU coordinates (East, North, Up, corresponding to your local XYZ system) with [this rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_ECEF_to_ENU) (P0 can be the local reference point for the East-North-Up directions). Finally, divide your coordinates by (Time1 - Time0) to take into account the time component.

Comment: It worked.. I am writing again regarding the doubt. In case of a third point. 
P2 = (Lat2,Lon2, h2, time2)

We can calculate the ENU coordinates w.r.t the first point. Say, East component is xEast = [xEast1;xEast2]  and the time vector [time0;time1;time2].  So the Vx1, Vx2 would be Vx1 = xEast1/ time1-time0 and Vx2 = xEast2/time2-time1?? 
OR
Vx1 = xEast1/ time1-time0 and Vx2 = xEast2/time2-time0??

Comment: If you wish to calculate the vector from P0 to P2, then it will be (x2-x0) / (time2-time0), etc. If you need each vector individually, it is (x1-x0) / (time1-time0)... for Vector 1, and (x2-x1) / (time2-time1) for Vector 2